# How to add projected point coordinates to attribute table?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-10.6

I want to get the projected coordinates of each point into my attribute table? The software which I want to use can only compute Cartesian/projected files, and not data in lat long or any other kind of degrees and minutes situation.

I have XY Coordinates as Lat Long in my attribute table. I wish to obtain the projected coordinates for all of my points in meters as shown in the status bar in the bottom right corner. They are also identified as 'location' when i use the info button to click onto each point.

Comment: From your problem statement, it sounds like it's not the attribute table, but the data itself you want to project.  If the tool is only reading the attribute file, what is the format of the data? Which projection would be appropriate? There are a number of possible ways to reproject a point using Python, with or without the Field Calculator, plus good old Add XY Coordinates. What have you tried?  What problem did you encounter?

Comment: I have XY Coordinates as Lat Long in my attribute table. I wish to obtain the projected coordinates for all of my points in meters as shown in the status bar in the bottom right corner. They are also identified as 'location' when i use the info button to click onto each point.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to provide clarrifications.  Include: What is the coordinate system of the data? What is the map CS? Have you tried using Add XY Coordinates?

Comment: Vince, i've updated  my question does that help?

Comment: The title is just an advertising banner to get people to look at your question.  It shouldn't be packed with details, particularly details not present in the question body.  You should be shooting for several paragraphs in the question body. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. And welcome to GIS SE.

Comment: Check the Data Frame Properties in your map, under the Coordinate System tab. What is the current coordinate system being used? Once you know that, you can use the Calculate Geometry function in the attribute table, and specify the right coordinate system to get your x, y values.

Answer (score 1):

> How to add projected point coordinates to attribute table?

This can be done by adding two new fields to your attribute table, then using the calculate geometry tool for each field. This will add attributes which contain the x,y coordinates *at this time*. If you edit the data (move a point), the value in these fields will **not** automatically update.

1. Set your dataframe to the desired output coordinate system (sounds like you already have if the coordinates in the bottom right are showing your desired coordinates/units).
2. Open the attribute table.
3. From the table options, click Add Field. Name it something like x_coord. Change the field type to Float.
   *Note:* Float and double are the numeric data types that allow for decimals. Double has 15 decimal digits of precision, while float has 7. Remember, GIS software will encode as many decimal places as are possible in the field's data type. This WILL produce false precision past the spatial accuracy of your data. e.g. The longitude of 70.5° W might work out to 866.117m when projected into some local projection, when clearly 70.5° is isn't accurate to the nearest millimeter. Just keep that in mind...
4. Add another field and name it y_coord.
5. On the attribute table, right click on the x_coord field. Click "Calculate geometry". It will warn you that you are editing outside and edit session. That's fine. Click "Yes".
6. Set the property to "X Coordinate of Point" and the Coordinate System to "Use coordinate system of the data frame". Click OK.
7. repeat 5-6 for the y_coord field, but change the property to "Y Coordinate of Point".

> The software which I want to use can only compute Cartesian/projected files.

If you need to upload a CSV or other text file with projected x/y coordinates, the method above will work for you.
If you need to upload a shapefile that uses a projected coordinate system, then you want to use the Data Management toolbox "Project" to file to create a new shapefile with the appropriate coordinates system. The new coordinates will be intrinsic to the data and will update if you edit and move points.